# What is the difference? two way to update list

Tags: reactjs

I have one list and i Need split in two list, this list can have updates because I have a lot of filters.

```
const List = ({list}) => {
  const [listA, setListA] = useState([]);
  const [listB, setListB] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setListA(list.filter(x => x.a === 0));
    setListB(list.filter(x => x.a !== 0));
  }, [list]);

  return (
    ......
  )
}
```

**VS**

```
const List = ({list}) => {
  const listA = list.filter(x => x.a === 0);
  const listB = list.filter(x => x.a !== 0);

  return (
    ......
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that, in the first case, you end up storing redundant information in state. Additionally, when your list changes you will run your effect, set the state for `listA` and `listB`, and end up with additional component renders.

Take [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sutherland-woh8l) codesandbox example. You can see in the console that our component renders twice: once for the initial render and once as a result of the effect calling `setState` for the new list. That's extra rendering!

Since you don't *need* to store `listA` and `listB` in state, I recommend you don't do so; they are "derived" state and can simply be calculated as a result of the `list` prop and your filters.